# serenity bdd: how to reuse test steps(@steps) as we do in cucumber BDD (i.e. using pico container )

Tags: bdd, serenity-bdd

Using Serenity BDD +selenium+Junit for automation.i have experience in cucumber BDD where we can easily share steps.i want to achieve the same in serenity. 
For simplicity let's say we have a **Login page** and a subsequent page say **Name Check Page**. I have created individual POM for these two pages and then corresponding step definitions(@steps) and wanted to use @steps defined in these two step definition classes in single script. Can this be done?

1. I have tried using this but browser closes as soon the step in particular step class finishes so other steps do not get executed and gives exception

   ```
   public class AA_NameCheck{

       @Managed(driver="edge",clearCookies=ClearCookiesPolicy.BeforeEachTest)
       WebDriver driver;

       @Steps
       StepsLoginPage stepL;
       StepsNameCheckPage stepN;

       @Test
       public void NameCheck_ValidUser() throws InterruptedException{
           stepL.Launch();
           stepL.Login_ValidCredential();
           stepN.Enter_NameDetails();

           }
   }
   ```

After `stepL.Login_validCredentials()` finishes browser gets close and thus exception occur on methods on `Name_EnterDetails()`

2. I have tried instead of creating separate step definition keeping the @steps in POM ,it worked but the steps are then not visible in serenity report.

**Just wanted to know any other approach is possible for sharing steps?**

***Sharing POM and Step Definition,Please have a look***

POM for Name Check Page:

```
public class NameCheckPage extends PageObject {

    public NameCheckPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    Actions action=new Actions(getDriver());


    @FindBy(id="xx")
    public WebElementFacade EngName;

    @FindBy(id="xx")
    public WebElementFacade SecondEngName;

    @FindBy(id="xx")
    public WebElementFacade ThirdEngName;


    @FindBy(xpath="xx")
    public List<WebElementFacade> NameCheckBtns;

    @FindBy(id="xx")
    public WebElementFacade PreliminaryStatusChk;


    public void Enter_FirstEngName() {
        EngName.isVisible();
        EngName.sendKeys("xylon");
    }

    public void Enter_EnglishName(String name) {
        EngName.isVisible();
        EngName.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void Enter_SecEngName() {
        SecondEngName.isVisible();
        SecondEngName.sendKeys("xylonone");
    }

    public void Enter_ThirdEngName() {
        ThirdEngName.isVisible();
        ThirdEngName.sendKeys("xylontwo");
    }

    public void Enter_FirstEngNameone() {
        EngName.isVisible();
        EngName.sendKeys("xylo");
    }

    public void Enter_SecEngNameone() {
        SecondEngName.isVisible();
        SecondEngName.sendKeys("xyloone");
    }

    public void Enter_ThirdEngNameone() {
        ThirdEngName.isVisible();
        ThirdEngName.sendKeys("xylotwo");
    }

    public void AddCompany() {

        action.click(NameCheckBtns.get(1)).perform();
    }

    public void AddSecondCompany() {
        action.click(NameCheckBtns.get(2)).perform();
        }

    public void PrelimCheck() throws InterruptedException {

        for(WebElement btns:NameCheckBtns) {
            System.out.println("Buttons :"+btns.getText());
        }

        System.out.println(NameCheckBtns.get(4).getText());


        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", NameCheckBtns.get(4));

        action.click(NameCheckBtns.get(4)).perform();
        PreliminaryStatusChk.isVisible();
        System.out.println(PreliminaryStatusChk.getText());
    }
```

Step Definition for Login Page:

```
public class StepsLoginPage extends ScenarioSteps  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    LoginPage login;

    @Step
    public void Launch() {
    login.Launch();
    }
    @Step
    public void Login_ValidCredential() {
        login.Launch();
        login.Enter_Username();
        login.Enter_Password();
        login.Click_LoginBtn();
         //tried using return but of no help the browser still closes
        //return new NameCheckPage(login.getDriver());
}
```

Step Definition for Name Check Page:

```
public class StepsNameCheckPage extends ScenarioSteps{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    NameCheckPage namechk;
    @Step
    public void Enter_NameDetails() throws InterruptedException {
        namechk.Enter_FirstEngName();
        namechk.AddCompany();
        namechk.Enter_SecEngName();
        namechk.AddCompany();
        namechk.Enter_ThirdEngName();
        namechk.PrelimCheck();
}
```

Test:

```
public class AA_NameCheck{

    @Managed(driver="edge",clearCookies=ClearCookiesPolicy.BeforeEachTest)
    WebDriver driver;

    @Steps
    StepsLoginPage stepL;
    StepsNameCheckPage stepN;

    @Test
    public void NameCheck_ValidUser() throws InterruptedException{
        stepL.Launch();
        stepL.Login_ValidCredential();
        stepN.Enter_NameDetails();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show should work fine, so I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: i have updated the question with POM and step definition file,Please have a look

Answer (score -1):

When you are using two classes with steps in annotation `@Steps` you should have:

```
@Steps
StepsLoginPage stepL; 
@Steps 
StepsNameCheckPage stepN;
```

In your case second class is null.